# swift Passing data from containverView error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Heloo, i have this problem when im using contaienerView with static tableview. i want to pass my data from my main view controller to my tableview, and im having this break where it said my data is null, but it wasnt null because i already fill that data that i want to pass in. im using firebase and dictionary. heres my code :

my main controller :

```
class MainController: UITableViewController, AddPatientController {

private var patientLists = [PatientList]() // empty array buat isi list yg isinya nama pasien
var Segue : String = "PatientName"
var Segue2 : String = "PatientNotes"
let user : User = Auth.auth().currentUser! 
private var rootRef : DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.rootRef = Database.database().reference() 
    populateList()
}

private func populateList() {// 5. func buat fetch data dari db ke hp



    self.rootRef.child(self.user.emailWithoutSpecialChar).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in 

        self.patientLists.removeAll()

        let pasienListDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]  ?? [:] //7. ini berarti return buat kl dict nya kosong, ini buat akses ke valuenya yg isinya itu dict[String:Any]

        for (key,_) in pasienListDict {

            if let pasienlistdict = pasienListDict[key] as? [String:Any]{


                if let pasienlist = PatientList(pasienlistdict) {
                    self.patientLists.append(pasienlist)
                    // ini buat ngemasukin ke dalem dictionarynya, ini buat store datanya dan ngambil datanya dari firebase db
                }

            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

} override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == Segue {
        let nc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let addPatientName = nc.viewControllers.first as! AddListController
        addPatientName.delegate = self

        }

        else if segue.identifier == Segue2 {

        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}

        let nc = segue.destination as! PasienProfileController
        nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row] 
    }

}
```

and this is my controller that should recieve the data

```
class NotesController: UITableViewController, AddNotesDelegate {


var pasien : PatientList!
private var rootRef : DatabaseReference! 



var Segue1 : String = "AddNotes"
var Segue2 : String = "PasienNotes"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = pasien.name // this is the line where my code break cause it says the data is null

    self.rootRef = Database.database().reference()

}
```

my pasienprofilecontroller and my pasienProfileTableController( the containverView one) :

```
class PasienTableController: UITableViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var dataKunjunganLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var diagnosaPasienLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var alergiPasienLbl: UILabel!

var delegete : PasienTableControllerDelegate?

var patientList = [PatientList]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self


}

class PasienProfileController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var TinggiLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var beratLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var GolDarahLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var NamaLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var ImagePic: UIImageView!

var pasien : PatientList!

@IBOutlet weak var ContainerView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.ImagePic.makeRounded()
    self.NamaLbl.text = pasien.name

}
```

this is the image of my storyboard to get a clear picture of what im trying to do

[image: so my "Patient" view controller is my main controller, which after that it will show the profile pasien controller, which is uiview with container view that contain static tableview. and when i try to hit that " Data Kunjungan Pasien" Cell, it gets the error.]

so my "Patient" view controller is my main controller, which after that it will show the profile pasien controller, which is uiview with container view that contain static tableview. and when i try to hit that " Data Kunjungan Pasien" Cell, it gets the error

so is theres something wrong with my logic? why it keep saying null while it can successfully show the data from Patient view to patientProfileView?

*this is my git if you guys wanna clone and check my error https://gitlab.com/afipermanaa/skripsi.git

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried setting some breakpoints? Either the assignment isn't executing or viewDidLoad is being called before the assignment.

Comment: i already set a breakpoint and it says that my data that im trying to send is nil, im using dictionary to save the data and pass the data from each view controller, i have a feeling that when i press one of my patient from my patient list, the app doesnt know which of the patient is been press and send to my tableview thats why it crashed. but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: You aren't sending nil data. Either viewDidLoad is called before this line: `nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]`. Or, `nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]` isn't executing at all.

Comment: nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row] is send data from my main controller into my  pasienProfileController, and from my pasienProfileController. looks like i havent send the data from my pasienProfileController and i dont know how to send it.... i update the the code

Comment: so i think i have to send it one by one per viewController which i dont know how to do it....

Comment: Understanding the code flow will help. Replace this `nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]` with this `print(self.patientLists[indexPath.row]` and add a break point here `self.title = pasien.name`. Run your code and observe what prints (that will ensure you're not passing nil data) and look at what code executes before you get to the breakpoint as shown in the function list calls in the Navigator on the left side of XCode. That will indicate if the var is being accessed *before* it's populated. That's how you troubleshoot code - breakpoints and watching what order functions are called.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the tips, looks like i do passing nil data, but its weird cause that data that i try to pass is use on my pasienProfileController and its also consist "self.NamaLbl.text = pasien.name", which is the same pasien var that in my tableView. but in my pasienProfileController doesnt break while in my table breaks. my tableView comes after pasienProfileController

Answer (score 1):

I dont get it
if you want to pass the data from prepareForSegue with this code

```
    else if segue.identifier == Segue2 {

    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}

    let nc = segue.destination as! PasienProfileController
    nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row] 
}
```

to NotesController why do you cast "nc" as PasienProfileController ?
its not the same class

i don't see where you set pasien value.

I hope it helps you if not please explain

Answer (score 0):

cannot comment due to low rep, so I tried to explain it as clear as possible.

you may try to define that variable

```
private var patientLists = [PatientList]()
```

as static like below.

```
private static var patientLists = [PatientList]()
```

when you try to pass it through segue with this code

```
let nc = segue.destination as! PasienProfileController
    nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]
```

your class creates a new instance of patientList array when there is 'self'. so, when you define as static, there won't be any new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static var patientLists = [PatientList]()
```